# The action 'Search' cannot be found for InboxController

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to add a search bar. I have also set the path. But everytime I try to click on search it directs me to this error. What is the error in this code?

This is my Inbox_Controller file. It says that the action 'Search' cannot be found in InboxController.

```
 class InboxController < ApplicationController
 before_action :valid_membership
 before_action :change_password_next_login
 before_action :agreed_to_terms
 before_action :allowed_send_mail?

 layout 'inbox'

 def bulk
 puts params

 ids = params[:bulk_ids]

 if ids
  params[:commit]

  case params[:commit]
    when 'Archive'
      ids.each do |id|
        message = Message.find(id)
        message.archived = true
        message.save()
      end
    when 'Restore'
      ids.each do |id|
        message = Message.find(id)
        message.archived = false
        message.save()
      end
    else
      puts 'invalid action!!'
  end


  if params[:folder] != ''
    redirect_to inbox_index_path(folder: params[:folder])
  else
    redirect_to inbox_index_path
  end
 else
  flash[:alert] = t('errors.inbox.no_emails_selected')
  redirect_to :back
 end
 end

def index

per_page = 10
page = params[:page] ? params[:page] : 1
@inbox = Inbox.search(params[:search])
  case params[:folder]
  when 'archive'
    @messages = current_user.archived_messages(page, per_page)
  when 'drafts'
    @messages = current_user.draft_messages(page, per_page)
  when 'sent'
    @messages = current_user.sent_messages(page, per_page)
  else
    @messages = current_user.received_messages(page, per_page)
  end

  end

  def reply
  original = Message.find(params[:id])
  @quoted = "\n\nOn #{original.sent_time.strftime("%m/%d/%y %-I:%M %p")}, # {original.from.full_name} wrote:\n----------------\n#{original.body}"
@message = Message.new(
    :parent => original,
    :to => original.from,
    :subject => "RE: #{original.subject}",
    :body => @quoted,
)

render :compose
end

def move
@message = Message.find(params[:id])
folder = params[:destination]

case folder
  when 'archive'
    @message.archived = true
  else
    @message.archived = false
end

unless @message.save
  puts @message.errors.full_messages
end

redirect_to inbox_index_path(folder: folder)
end

def show
@message = Message.find(params[:id])

if !@message.read? && @message.to == current_user
  @message.read_time = DateTime.now
  unless @message.save
    puts @message.errors.full_messages
  end
end
end

def edit
@message = Message.find(params[:id])
@message.to_name = @message.to.full_name
render 'compose'
end

  def compose
   @message = Message.new
   if(params[:id])
     @message.to = Mentor.find(params[:id])
   end

  end

  def create
    if(params[:message] && !params[:message][:id].empty?)
      @message = Message.find(params[:message][:id])
      @message.assign_attributes(message_params)
    else
      @message = Message.new(message_params)
    end

     if params[:parent_id] && !params[:parent_id].empty?
     @message.parent = Message.find(params[:parent_id])
     @message.replied_to_time = Time.now
    end
    @message.from = current_user

    draft = params[:draft]

    if draft
      @message.draft = true
    else
      @message.sent_time = Time.now
      @message.draft = false
    end

     # puts @message.as_json
    if can_send_mail
      if @message.save
        if !draft
          if current_user_or_guest.mentee?
            current_user.credits += -1
            current_user.save
          end

         UserMailer.inmail_notification(@message).deliver
        end

        redirect_to inbox_index_path(folder: draft ? 'drafts' : 'inbox'), notice: "Message successfully #{draft ? 'saved' : 'sent'}."
      else
        flash.now[:alert] = 'All email fields need to be filled out prior to sending/saving.'
        render 'compose'
      end
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = 'You do not have enough credits to send any more    InMail to Game Changers.'
      render 'compose'
    end
   ActivityLog.create(userid: current_user.id, points: 500, typeof: "message")
  end 

  def allowed_send_mail?
    unless !current_user.admin?
      msg = "You are not authorized to access this page!"
     show_error(msg)
   end
  end

  def profile_complete
    return true if current_user.mentor?

    unless current_user.profile_complete?
      flash[:alert] = t('errors.inbox.incomplete_profile')
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    end
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:id, :to_name, :to_id, :subject, :body)
  end
end
```

This is my relevant index.erb.html file.

```
<%= form_tag inbox_search_path, :method => 'get' do %>
    <p>
      <%= search_field_tag :Search, params[:search] %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

This is my relevant routes.rb file:

```
 get 'inbox' => 'inbox#index', :as => 'inbox_index'
 get 'inbox/show/:id' => 'inbox#show', :as => 'inbox_show'
 get 'inbox/compose' => 'inbox#compose', :as => 'inbox_compose'
 get 'inbox/compose/:id' => 'inbox#compose', :as => 'inbox_compose_to'
 get 'inbox/edit/:id' => 'inbox#edit', :as => 'inbox_edit'
 get 'inbox/move' => 'inbox#move', :as => 'inbox_move'
 get 'inbox/reply' => 'inbox#reply', :as => 'inbox_reply'
 get 'inbox/search' => 'inbox#search', :as => 'inbox_search'
 post 'inbox/create' => 'inbox#create'
 post 'inbox/bulk' => 'inbox#bulk'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no search method in this controller, the only search I see is a call to Inbox.search.

To debug this, start with the view where you actually do the "click".  Is that click really supposed to trigger an action in your InboxController?  If you think it should, why is there no action in that controller?  If not, then the "click" was meant to go to another controller that actually would handle the search action, in which case you need to figure out why the "click" is trying to call a method in your InboxController rather than the desired controller.  The problem could be something in your view or something in you routes,  or you really should have that method in you InboxController, either way I suggest you try to figure out at least what should be happening and then post some more code stating what you think should be happening vs what is really happening.

Comment: So when I define a different method for search in the controller, it shows me a different error message. I just added the code in my index method in the controller. I am unable to figure it out. Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: so are you saying that you now have the same code that you show above for the index method as your search method?  otherwise show what you now have in your search method and what the error currently is

Comment: I currently have the search in the index method. Should I be defining the new search method.

Comment: yes,  the way you have your view and routes setup, when you click the search button a get request is set to inbox/search which is routed to inbox#search,  which means it is trying to call a method search in your inbox controller, but it is not defined

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So I am adding the self search method in my messages.rb model file. And I am trying to call that method in my controllers file. Can you guide me how would I go with that?

Comment: So first of all you don't _have_ to have a search method,  you could just have the search button be routed to the index method by using inbox_index_path rather than inbox_search_path.  As far as the search method itself, once you have the correct data arriving in the correct method of the correct controller (which is step 1) then you if you have a working class methd (self.search) in your Message model, you just call it with something like @messages = Message.search(params[:search]).  If you end up having trouble with that part you may want to ask a second question

Comment: So I have done the latter part of the solution you showed. I have a self.search method and I also have @message= Message.search(params[:search]). So you are telling me something is wrong with the route I have set?

Comment: I tried that. But it gives me this error. Missing template inbox/search, application/search with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/home/shaili/thescla/app/views" * "/home/shaili/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise_security_extension-0.8.0/app/views" * "/home/shaili/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views"

Comment: right, because now it is looking for a view to render called search, by default rails, at the end of a controller method rails tries to render a view with the same name as the method.  The initial problem you had was that because you had inbox_search_path  and a route matching that to a search method that is were it sent the search data ... it sounds like you really just wanted to use your index method ... try chainging inbox_search_path to inbox_index_path in your form, the confirm that you get the search field data there , maybe a puts "i got #{params[:search]}" in your index method

Comment: Wait, so when I changed my form to inbox_index_path I got this error. Should I add@message = Message.search(params[:search]) in the index method?

Comment: When I do that it gives me the error The action 'Search' cannot be found for InboxController.

Comment: if the search field is just to filter out what would normally be returned by your index then, yes that what I would do

Comment: It gave me the error The action 'Search' cannot be found for InboxController

Comment: so what you really want to do is just take a few moments to make sure you understand exactly what happens when you click your button.  It's not magic,  rails just takes the data in your form and sends it to a controller method.  so first get that part working ... be 100% sure you understand which controller method is being called and what parameters it is receiving ,  you can do this by just adding a printf to your index method and one 2 your search method.

Comment: puts i mean ... so in your index add puts "index was called with #{params}" in your search put puts "search was called with #{params}"

Comment: I did that and it is still giving me an error of a missing template. What should I do about it?

Comment: Am I supposed to add a new search file in views?